# Git plumbing command to find out which files have been changed in a given revision

Tags: git, githooks

I've created a hook that sends out notification emails when a developer pushes an update to his shared repository. This email includes a list of changed files, example:

```
A   __classes/Page/Activity.php
M   __config/Scheme.php
```

that I generate using the following bit of bash:

```
$(git diff "$newrev"^ "$newrev" --name-status)
```

This works fine. However, I'm trying to port all this now to the well-known [post-receive-email hook](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob_plain;f=contrib/hooks/post-receive-email;hb=HEAD). This hook does have a `hooks.showrev` configuration directive, but this I think this only allows for the revision number (`%s`) to be used *once* in the command. So this doesn't work:

```
showrev = "git diff %s^ %s --name-status"
```

There must be a 'plumbing' command that does just this. Can anyone point me in the right direction? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the following?

```
showrev = "git show --name-status --pretty=format: %s"
```

`git show` is porcelain rather than plumbing, but I think this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, it does do what I want! Clever, setting format to empty. :) I'm now trying to get the command to display `[commit message]\n\n> [date]\n> [hash]`, but it doesn't work yet. I've done this on the command line using `showrev = "git log -1 --format='%b%n%n> %ad%n> %H' %s"`, but I'm getting some errors about the `%n`.

Comment: These are the exact errors: `remote: printf: 739: %n: invalid directive`, `remote: eval: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Rijk: try using `%%n` instead - in `printf`-style formatting strings that's how you escape a `%` sign.

Comment: Right on, that was it. I also was mistaking the `%b` for commit message, which is actually `%s`. `showrev = "git log -1 --format='%%s%%n%%n> %%ad%%n> %%H' %s"`, that's it. :)

Comment: @Rijk: great, I'm glad to hear that's working for you now.  I think my answer still answers your original question, though, so I won't edit it further :)

Answer (score 1):

`git whatchanged -1 <rev>` might be a good starting point, and has a number of additional options for massaging the output format. Not sure you can get exactly the format you quoted above, but you should be able to get something comparable.